# why symbolic matrix is not properly displayed in LaTeX?

Tags: matrices

I'm not able to get the output of this matrix in clear way, is poorly displayed, what to do?

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
G(s)=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1.24}{s^3 + 0.9215 s^2 + 4.413 s + 3.617} & 0 \\
\frac{1.482 s + 0.4243}{s^4 + 6.333s^3 + 7.083s^2 + 2.083s} & 
\frac{3.6}{s^3 + 6 s^2 + 5 s}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to make it "better" but I suggest using `\dfrac` to put the fractions into "display mode" and adding extra space between the rows by adding `\\[4mm]` at the end of the first row. This gives:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  G(s)=\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{1.24}{s^3 + 0.9215 s^2 + 4.413 s + 3.617} & 0 \\[4mm]
    \dfrac{1.482 s + 0.4243}{s^4 + 6.333s^3 + 7.083s^2 + 2.083s} &
    \dfrac{3.6}{s^3 + 6 s^2 + 5 s}
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```